# Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). )"

Tags: java, proxy, http-proxy, alm

I am trying to run a jar and getting below exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.econ.alm.core.ALMConnector.doHttp(ALMConnector.java:182)
```

Code snippet:

```
InetSocketAddress sd = new InetSocketAddress("XXX.XXX.X.XXX",80);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,sd);
HttpURLConnection con =
(HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);


con.setRequestMethod(type);
String cookieString = getCookieString();

prepareHttpRequest(con, headers, data, cookieString); //User defined function to set content type for con object

con.connect(); //Statement which is generating error
```

What are the reasons to get such error?

Comment: You should show us the code (if you have) or the URL you use ... Perhaps you use ftp:// or something your proxy does not support